# Checking if string has letter e (case insensitive) sql query using one where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am practising on a website, where they ask me to show a list of players with an 'e' or 'E' in their name using only one WHERE condition.

My query shows the same output as what is expected, yet the website is saying 'I did something that is not right or result is incomplete'.

Does my WHERE statement count as one condition? Is there a way to be case insensitive only after the LIKE?

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.spelersnr, voorletters || ' ' || naam AS spelersnaam
FROM spelers s INNER JOIN wedstrijden w
     ON s.spelersnr = w.spelersnr

WHERE LOWER(naam) LIKE '%e%'

ORDER BY s.spelersnr ASC
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih im using pgAdmin and sql dropbox, I think postgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your database supports a `LOWER` function, then your current `WHERE` clause would already seem to be one condition:

```
WHERE LOWER(naam) LIKE '%e%'
```

In Postgres, you could also write this using `SIMILAR TO`:

```
WHERE naam SIMILAR TO '%(e|E)%'
```

Or, you could use a POSIX regular expression:

```
WHERE naam ~* '.*e.*'
```

Comment: Those are two new ways I didnt know, thnx.

Answer (score 1):

as you mentioned it is postgres db, using similar to or like will help. a detailed explanation is in below link 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.spelersnr, voorletters || ' ' || naam AS spelersnaam
FROM spelers s INNER JOIN wedstrijden w
     ON s.spelersnr = w.spelersnr

WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (naam, '(.)*e(.)*', 'i')

ORDER BY s.spelersnr ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `ILIKE`:

```
WHERE naam ILIKE '%e%'
```

This is built-in Postgres operator that does case-insensitive matching.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html).